# Community Promotion Ads for 2011

Tags: discussion, promotion

When will the webapps community be able to promote Web Applications for new visitors to the site ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only had to ask.

[Community Promotion Ads - 2H 2011](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/829)

Comment: I was shy to do so XD